# Two public IPs from a single interface to two routers

Tags: routing, ipv4

My ISP provides me with two static public IP addresses which come in on the same ethernet wire.  I want to use two routers (running OpenWrt) with one public IP per router.  To achieve this, I have a Debian 11 machine (which I will call "the box") to direct traffic for each IP to its respective router.

So I want traffic for IP `X.X.X.2` to go to Router A and traffic for `X.X.X.3` to go to Router B.  The ISP provided `X.X.X.1` as the gateway address.  These are all global IP addresses.  In this example, I've named the interfaces "wan", "lan1", and "lan2" as below:

```
               ISP
                │
           ┌────▼─────┐
           │   wan    │
           │          │
           │ THE BOX  │
           │          │
     ┌─────┤lan1  lan2├────┐
     │     └──────────┘    │
     │                     │
┌────▼─────┐          ┌────▼─────┐
│   wan    │          │   wan    │
│          │          │          │
│ ROUTER A │          │ ROUTER B │
│          │          │          │
└──────────┘          └──────────┘
```

What I've tried to do is assign `X.X.X.2/32` to Router A's wan interface.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but my thinking is that none of the box's interfaces should be assigned an IP address, because it only forwards traffic, and is not the final destination for any packets.  I suppose this means it will be unable to access the internet itself.

With the static address and routes configured, Router A looks like this:

```
root@RouterA:~# ip addr show dev wan
7: wan@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet X.X.X.2/32 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global wan    
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@RouterA:~# ip route
default via X.X.X.1 dev wan
X.X.X.1 dev wan scope link
```

And on the box, I set no static IPs on any interfaces and created these static routes:

```
root@TheBox:~# ip route
default via X.X.X.1 dev wan
X.X.X.1 dev wan scope link
X.X.X.2 dev lan1 scope link
X.X.X.3 dev lan2 scope link
```

Then I try to ping the ISP's gateway address (`X.X.X.1`) from Router A and get 100% packet loss.  To check that the packets are being sent to the box correctly, I ran a packet sniffer on the box and got some ARP requests:

```
root@TheBox:~# tcpdump -i lan1 -vv
14:55:48.202508 ARP, Etherenet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has X.X.X.1 tell X.X.X.2, length 46
14:55:49.212438 ARP, Etherenet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has X.X.X.1 tell X.X.X.2, length 46
14:55:50.252491 ARP, Etherenet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has X.X.X.1 tell X.X.X.2, length 46
```

The fact that the box has no assigned IP address makes me think that I might need to hardcode the gateway's MAC address in there somewhere.  That's as far as I've gotten; I don't know much about layer 2.

**Similar questions:**

- [How to assign IPs in server interfaces when connected to two similar routers [closed]](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45658/): Vague wording, doesn't answer my question
- [Two routers, one modem, dual IPs, second address drops connection occasionally](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47765/): Same setup but with a different OS and solution was "defective router"

Comment: But why?... Why would you run machine with routing and stuff? Simply connect a cheap network switch and it works without issue.

Comment: I think that first post is stating you need to assign the ISP provided IP addresses to the LAN interfaces on "the box" versus assigning those to the WAN interfaces on the router. Otherwise, you might need some sort of NAT'd configuration pointing "the box" interfaces to the WAN assigned router IPs. It's been a while since I had to deal with any complex routing but it's usually firewall appliance level stuff for me there when I do have to get involved.

Comment: @YisroelTech  Of course.